# Smooth scrolling in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019

it seems quite obvious that and IDE should have smooth scrolling capability, but looks like VS2019 just does not have such option in the settings. There even is a plugin for this specific function, but it seems that it often does not work with VS2019. Let alone that it is a third-party software, probably with less than perfect integration with the IDE, suboptimal efficiency and so on. YouTube gives absolutley zero result on this topic. Am I missing something?

Comment: It scrolls smooth for me. Post more information, like what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: When I move the mousewheel by one click, it moves the code by 3 lines (there is an option called "Vertical Scrolling Sensitivity" that says just that). But I want it to move smoothly like IG feed on mobile devices for example. Or like any normal website would behave. Also, I have found an option called "Enable rich client visual experience", but it did not help, even after restart.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way to do that with the text editor logic. Just FYI it's always been this way since olden VS and up to VS 2022.